# A map that is surjective but not injective between infinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F^{\infty}$ be the $F$-vector space of infinite sequences $(x_1,x_2,...)$. Let the map
$\phi:F^{\infty}\longrightarrow F^{\infty};\;(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\longmapsto (x_1+x_2,x_2,\cdots)$.
I know that this map is not  injective, but i can't find two distinct elements with same image. thank you for help.

Comment: Why do you think it's not injective?

Comment: This is the usual example given for a linear map that is surjective but not injective in infinite dimensional vector spaces. As long as the map $(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\longmapsto (0,x_1,x_2, \cdots)$ is injective but not surjective.

Comment: The "typical" example is a shift map instead: $(x_1,x_2,\dots)\mapsto(x_2,x_3,\dots)$.

Comment: ok I see. Thank you Andres !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This map is actually injective. To see this let $x,y\in F^{\infty}$ where $x = (x_1,x_2,...)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2,...)$. Then suppose $\phi x = \phi y$, i.e.

$$ (x_1 + x_2, x_2, x_3,...) = (y_1 + y_2, y_2, y_3,...).$$

The conditions after the first term say that $x_i=y_i \,\forall i\ge 2$. Therefore $x_1+x_2 = y_1+y_2 \Rightarrow x_1 = y_1$ since $x_2 = y_2$. We have $\phi x = \phi y \Rightarrow x = y$ and thus this is an injective mapping.

Answer (score 2):

The map is injective: its inverse is the map $$\langle x_0,x_1,x_2\ldots\rangle\mapsto\langle x_0-x_1,x_1,x_2,\ldots\rangle\;.$$

Alternatively, note that if $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\ker\varphi$, then $x_0+x_1=0=x_1$, so $x_0=0$, and clearly $x_k=0$ for $k>1$, so $x=0$.